# Azure Media Services for transcoding and delivering audio

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have a common use case scenario where I want to do the following

- Upload an audio file. (wav/mp3)
- Transcodes to 128k or 192k mp3.
- Stores the audio asset.
- Allows the audio asset to be streamed.
- Supports streaming actions such as play pause and seek.

The documentation for azure media services seems like it might be able to support this but I am not too sure, seems like they focus on video content. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage audio and encode audio only assets with azure media services.

WAV is supported input format/conatiner as a input asset. To see full list of supported formats check following link: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-media-encoder-standard-formats/

Check https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/media-services/media-services-custom-mes-presets-with-dotnet.md#audio_only to see audio only preset options which you will use to encode an audio only preset.

Comment: there is example how to submit and encode audio only mp3 file . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519305/how-to-stream-audio-on-android-using-azure-media-services/24622633#24622633